# Dropdown for Saving Model Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The code will not save the value to the Musician Entity.
I'm using a ViewBag that is saving a SelectList and it displays the content from the database but on save it is null for the musician.PrimaryInstrument field when debugging.
Razor :

```
<td>                           
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimaryInstrument, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
</td>
<td>
  @Html.DropDownList("InstrumentList")
</td>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
  if (id == null)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  Musician musician = (Musician)db.Contractor.Find(id);
  if (musician == null)
  {
    return HttpNotFound();
  }
  ViewBag.InstrumentList = new SelectList(db.Instrument, "ID", "Name");
  return View(musician);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Musician musician, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (image != null)
    {
      UploadImage(musician, image);
    }
    musician.YearsOfExperience = Convert.ToInt16(Request["yearsOfExperience"]);
    musician.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    musician.NextDateAvailable = DateTime.Now;
    db.Entry(musician).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges(); 
    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
  }
  return View();
}
```

Instrument Model:

```
    public class Instrument
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public ICollection<Musician> Musician { get; set; }
}
```

}

Musician Model:

```
  public class Musician : Contractor
{
    [Display(Name="Primary Instrument")]
    public string PrimaryInstrument { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Primary Genre")]
    public string PrimaryGenre { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Website Link")]
    public string WebsiteLink { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Youtube Link")]
    public string YouTubeLink { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "SoundCloud Link")]
    public string SoundCloudLink { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "ReverbNation Link")]
    public string  ReverbNationLink { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Instrument> Instruments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to bind to the property `PrimaryInstrument`? (i.e. set the value of `PrimaryInstrument` to the selected instrument list). You need to show your models for `Musician` and `PrimaryInstrument`.

Comment: Yes I am trying to bind the property to PrimaryInstrument field for the Musician entity with the value from the dropdown. The dropdown populates but will not save the value to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not currently binding the selected instrument to the property `PrimaryInstrument`. Your helper should be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PrimaryInstrument, (SelectList)ViewBag.InstrumentList)
```

Note this will bind the `ID` property of `Instrument` to the property `PrimaryInstrument`

Note also that if `ModelState` is not valid, you also need to reassign the `ViewBag.InstrumentList` property - `ViewBag.InstrumentList = new SelectList(db.Instrument, "ID", "Name");` before you call `return View(musician);`